# how to change the product video in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, file-upload, video

I am using  Magento ver. 1.9.2.3. Here how to change the product videos. I am not seeing the any video_url attributes in the admin panel.please advise me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does not provide video in product page.

You can add in description or create new attribute.
Check here
http://www.demagento.com/how-to-add-magento-product-video-programmatically/

Comment: where the uploaded video is saved.Help me the file path of that uploaded video.
Is this possible to upload video only by using admin panel without using any extension.